# При щелке в определенное место страницы персонаж на неё переместился

Tags: php, html, javascript

Ребят, совсем ещё нубик и новичок, а нигде помочь мне не могут.
Я хочу сделать так, чтобы при щелке в определенное место страницы персонаж на неё переместился, но совершенно не представляю, как это сделать. Может поможете? Буду очень благодарна!

Comment: Мне кажется php тут не причем. Все реализуется с помощью javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понял, вы имеете в виду перемещение элемента веб-страницы? Вам поможет `position: absolute` и манипулирование свойствами `left` и `top` соответствующего DOM-элемента средствами javascript.

И [простенький пример](http://jsbin.com/hohizaci/1) для старта.

Comment: Интересный эффект получается когда вашему блоку добавить скажем: transition: all 0.3s 0s;